# Redirect if conditions are met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How would I go about redirecting to another react page with `react-router@6` if conditions are not met? I was attempting to use this in the body of the component, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
const Basket = () => {
  redirect("/login")

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h2>Basket</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Basket;
```

Bear in mind I haven't yet programmed the if statement, but it will eventually look like this:

```js
if (currentUser != null) {
  <redirect here>
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) is a utility function only valid in RRDv6.4+ route loader and action functions. It's not valid to call in a React component. If you want to issue a redirect from the UI you can use either the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook (*via `navigate` function*) to issue an imperative redirect ***or*** render the [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component for a declarative redirect.

### Imperative Redirect

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Basket = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      navigate("/login", { replace: true });
    }
  }, [navigate, currentUser]);

  ...

  if (!currentUser) {
    // early return to not leak basket UI, if necessary
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h2>Basket</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Declarative Redirect

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Basket = () => {
  ...

  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h2>Basket</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Suggestion

Instead of checking the user's authentication status in the routed components it likely preferable to implement protected routes instead.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  ...get currentUser ...

  if (currentUser === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
   }

  return currentUser
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
};
```

Then wrap the sets of routes you want to protect.

```
<Router>
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
    <Route path="/basket" element={<Basket />} />
    ... other protected routes ...
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  ... other unprotected routes ...
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function LoginPage() {
    if (currentUser !== null) {
        return <Navigate to='/some-where-else' />
    } else {
        // Maybe a login form?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer an `useEffect` approach, in case `currentUser` is not defined or set in the first render.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Basket = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!currentUser) {
      <Redirect to="/any-route-you-want" />
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <div className="box">
        <h2>Basket</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Good point. OP could also invert the logic too as both `null` and `undefined` are falsey. Example: `if (currentUser)`.

Comment: `Redirect` isn't a `react-router-dom@6` component. Also, `<Redirect to="/any-route-you-want" />` alone in the `useEffect` will do nothing.

Comment: Sorry, one more. The `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the render cycle, so the check for a `currentUser` will happen *after* the component has rendered once. You'll want to also check `currentUser` prior to the normal render return in case there's a dependency, like `currentUser.username` which will throw an exception if `currentUser` is null/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to archieve that if the User is not LoggedIn use:

**Pure React:**

```
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const loader = async () => {
  const user = await getUser(); //function which retrieves e.g. the user from DB
  if (!currentUser) {
    return redirect("/login");
  }
  return null;
};
```

**For the Next.js (React Framework):**

**useEffect()** hook with **useRouter()**. Try something like this:

```
  const {currentUser} = useAuth(); //you are getting the user from DB
  const router = useRouter(); // importing the router usage

    useEffect(() => {
            if(!currentUser) { //if there is not user push me to the login
                router.push('/login')  
            }
        }, [router, currentUser]) // dependencies - watch for the changes
```